# Splitting a line read from input with and without fmap in haskell

Tags: haskell

I found out that `words` is the appropriate function to split a `String`:

`words :: String -> [String]`

What's special about `fmap` that makes this code work:

```
Prelude> fmap words getLine
abc def ghi
["abc","def","ghi"]
```

and it's omission results in a error:

```
Prelude> words getLine

<interactive>:10:7: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: IO String
    • In the first argument of ‘words’, namely ‘getLine’
      In the expression: words getLine
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = words getLine
```

I know that `fmap` works with `Functors` but I don't know about `Functors` yet. Is it related to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLine` returns an `IO String`, so `words getLine` is a type error. `fmap` has type

```
Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and `IO` has a functor instance so `fmap` for `IO` has type `(a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b`. `fmap words` therefore has type `IO String -> IO [String]`, and applying this to the result of `getLine` results in an `IO [String]`.

In ghci, `IO` actions are executed an their results printed, which is why you see the result list displayed.

Comment: You're missing a `->` in the type for `fmap`.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn - Thanks, fixed.